# DirectX 9 not rendering after adding transforms

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, direct3d, directx-9

so far I got a cube rendered without any transforms (thus it was rendered in an orthographic perspective), and I am working on the previous code to get it into a perspective view, with all the matrices involved. I changed the Flexible Vertex Format so as not to have RHW (thus only having XYZ coordinates and color, tried ARGB and XRGB but I don't think it matters), and I added a function that sets all the matrices.

**Debugging**
showed that matrices are being created correctly, functions return correctly (as far as I could see), no crashes (DirectX will never complain if something goes wrong, it just doesn't render) and in general, step-by-step debugging shows no paranormal activity.

**Existing project** (which I modify and eventually prevent from working):
As I advance I also write tutorials of sorts so I can go back and see what I did last time to get it to work, and this time I've kept versions so you can get the code [here](http://students.ceid.upatras.gr/~vpapadatos/DirectX9TutorialIndexedPrims.rar) along with the VS2010 solution, all the DirectX work is done in 3Dheader.h and D3DLoader.h

**Changes:**
 - the custom vertex format FVF_CUSTOMVERTEX has been changed so as not to include RHW, as I understand it has to be removed so as to be computed through the transformations
 - In `Render()` I add a call to the function `setMatrices()` which does all the matrix and transform work, and is as follows:

```
void setMatrices()
{
    //--------------transformation code----------------//
    D3DXMATRIX objectM, translationM, rotationM, projectionM, lookAtM, finalM;

HRESULT hr;

D3DXMatrixIdentity(&objectM);
D3DXMatrixRotationY(&rotationM, D3DX_PI/4);
//D3DXMatrixMultiply(&finalM, &objectM, &rotationM);

D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&projectionM,D3DX_PI/4,(float)yRes/xRes, 1, 100);

D3DXVECTOR3 camera;
camera.x = -10;
camera.y = 0;
camera.z = 0;
D3DXVECTOR3 cameraTarget;
cameraTarget.x = 0;
cameraTarget.y = 0;
cameraTarget.z = 0;
D3DXVECTOR3 cameraUp;
cameraUp.x = 0;
cameraUp.y = 1;
cameraUp.z = 0;
D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&lookAtM,&camera,&cameraTarget, &cameraUp);

hr = pd3dDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &objectM);
hr = pd3dDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &projectionM);
hr = pd3dDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &lookAtM);

D3DVIEWPORT9 view_port;

view_port.X=0;
view_port.Y=0;
view_port.Width=xRes;
view_port.Height=yRes;
view_port.MinZ=0.0f;
view_port.MaxZ=1.0f;

pd3dDevice->SetViewport(&view_port);
}
```

Note of course that some elements may not be needed, placed there just in case during my attempts, this is the code I have currently so we have a common reference.

Thanks in advance for any answers and/or attempts to answer.

Comment: Get a PIX capture. Usually it will be clear what's going wrong. In particular, look at the mesh tab.

Comment: Did you also change the position and size of the vertexes in you cube? World space coordinates are at different scale than transformed screen space coordinates.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito Had no idea PIX even existed, wow! Ok, the Mesh tab in the Details panel seems to be the only one I can get info from with my current reading, when I have `DrawIndexedPrimitives` selected, in the pre-Vertex Shader view I have a wireframe render, in post-VS absolutely nothing, and viewport has two horizontal lines which I suppose are just the window borders.

Comment: @RossRidge, Yes, the corners' coordinates are combinations of 1 and -1, as taken from a multitude of books and tutorials, before going 3D they were combinations of 200 and 400, so I believe I've got that right

Comment: Setting all matrices to the identity matrix got  the mesh into the viewport, but the render remains empty at all times... I also tried setting a material but no difference there. Also, once it is out of `DrawIndexedPrimitives` the mesh disappears again.

Comment: If the mesh appears in the preVS window, this means that you likely have the mesh input (FVF) set properly. The problem must then be with the matrices, or, with the pixel stage (or both). If the mesh does not appear in the third window (viewport space), it means that it is likely the matrices. You can look at the postVS tab, to see the values of the final output positions, which should be all 0..1, otherwise they will be outside the viewport.

Comment: Indeed some values our out of that range... But setting all matrices to the identity matrix, even though it does show much of the mesh in the viewport space, results in no output, would that indicate a bigger problem in the pixel stage (which I have had no contact with)? Also, should the mesh tab show any color or only wireframe?

Comment: You're going to have to provide a minimal complete and verifiable example. Otherwise we're just guessing. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yeah I guess it's not the most clear.... What I can say is that the position field has 4 numbers, in post the first one is -1.#IO, which leaves me clueless, the others are around -2, and 10, and some precise 11s. I provided a link to the project files, if you open it and change as described in the original post you'll doubtlessly get what I get - I've done this 2-3 times from scratch

Comment: that much is fixed, in PIX it's within the viewport, but nothing appears on render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code (downloaded), `xRes` and `yRes` are ints. Due to integer division, `yRes/xRes` will be zero, because xRes > yRes. You are passing this into the `D3DXMatrixPerspextiveFovLH` function as the aspect ratio, which will produce an invalid matrix. Instead, cast them to floats first, before doing the division, and pass the result in.

Comment: The good: I had that corrected at some point, but looks like I reverted at some point, so I am super glad you pointed that out. In PIX the mesh is inside the viewport. Also all values look perfectly right.
The bad: I don't get anything on Render (I see nothing in the application either of course).
I will take another very thorough look and see if I can spot anything wrong before I bug you any further.

Comment: By the way though, did it run for you? Though not probable, I may have tweaked something else, if it ran for you then it's probably solved.

Comment: I didn't try running it. If you have another issue, please post another question. SO works better when issues questions are as minimal as possible.

Comment: I'll debug some more today and see if it works out. The problem remained the same, as said in the question, it is not rendering - though undoubtedly progress has been made, and thank you for that. I asked so I knew if just rewriting the code would get it to run or not, which I will do anyway though.

Comment: I rewrote it as described throughout the question and it worked, looks like I had meddled with something else, thank you for your assistance.